# 3rd Euler Equation How to solve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I´m trying to solve this Euler-Cauchy equation $x^{3}y'''+2xy'-2y=x^2ln\left[x+3\right]$ using the video of this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9Qxq7Bd4aE, but searching here at the site here I ´ve found the method of substitution. Am I right?? What´s the best approach?

I know that i have in this case use $y=x^{m}$ and using derivatives of $y'=m*x^{m-1}$ and so on in plug into original equation where I have the y´s. In thi case Am I right about this approach?

I have found this caracteris[image]tic equation

But I have no ideia how to find the particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$
x^3y''' + 2xy' -2y = x^2\ln x + 3
$$
divide by $x^2$ we find
$$
xy''' + \frac{2}{x}y' - \frac{2}{x^2}y = xy''' + 2\frac{d}{dx}\frac{y}{x} =\ln x + \frac{3}{x^2}
$$ 
let $ y = vx$ we find
$$
y' = v'x + v\\
y'' = v''x + 2v'\\
y''' = v'''x + 3v''
$$
thus we get
$$
x^2v''' + 3xv'' +2v' = \ln x + \frac{3}{x^2}
$$
then set $v' = u$ then we get
$$
x^2u'' + 3xu' + 2u = \ln x + \frac{3}{x^2} 
$$
$\textbf{edit}$

I made a mistake before so in the aim of correction I edited accordingly!!

the homogeneous equation can probably be solved with $x^m$. 
$$
m(m-1)(m-2)x^{m} +2mx^{m} - 2x^{m}  = 0
$$
this leads to
$$
m(m-1)(m-2) + 2(m-1) = (m-1)\left(m^2-3m+4\right) =0\\
$$
therefore the three solutions are
$$
m_1 = 1\\
m_2 =\frac{3+i\sqrt{7}}{2}\\
m_3 =\frac{3-i\sqrt{7}}{2}
$$
thus your general solution would be of the form
$$
y_h = a_1x^{m_1} + a_2x^{m_2}+a_3x^{m_3}
$$

Comment: And if I try to use change of variables?

Comment: I have found for this case 3 roots, one real and two complex.

Comment: you were totally correct. I made a silly mistake!!

Comment: And What about the particular solution?